# Does fear of impending earthquakes because of a friend's remark amount to believing in omens (tiyarah)?

Tags: shirk

A friend once remarked something about earthquakes. Hearing such remarks, all of a sudden I started fearing that this might be a sign that an earthquake was upcoming. And I started praying that Allah not let such calamities befall me.

Is this 'tiyarah' (طیرہ)?  (Arabic word, also used in Quran, which means omen, and omen is defined as "an event regarded as a portent of good or evil" on [Google](https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=omen%20means&oq=omen%20means).)  Or is claiming to know the future as a result of such signs (by fearing that an earthquake would happen)?

When I was a child I used to think that sitting on particular seats would result in better results on exam day.  Is this belief in tiyarah?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE tha Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking some time to learn more about our site and model by taking our [tour](http://islam.stackexchange.com/tour) and visiting our [help](http://islam.stackexchange.com/help) center.

Answer (score 1):

**Assalam o alaikum:**

Firstly, welcome to the forum.

You have not explained anything about the remarks he was making, but it seems like that this is just an omen, because earthquakes cannot be caused by a person saying something, nor is he prophet or something that he is been somehow informed. So, this definitely is omen.

**Now coming to second part,** about sitting on specific seats for better results, i would say until or **unless you are planning to do some kind of cheating,** that is also an omen, because a seat can't cause you to perform better or worse. **Until or unless there is a cause, like a chair is broken, or somehow irritating or something which will divert your attention is in that chair, that's different.** But if chair is normal just like other chairs and you have no cheating plans, than this is also an omen. Have belief in allah.

And while you are asking if these are omens or not, i believe you know the status of omens in islam, and how islam discourages them. But still i will quote something about it to make answer complete:

> Ahmad (7045) and al-Tabaraani narrated that ‘Abd-Allaah ibn ‘Amr said:
>   The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him)
>   said: 
> **“Whoever lets tiyarah stop him from doing something is guilty of
>   shirk.”** They said, “What is the kafaarah for that?” He said, “To say:
>   Allaahumma la khayra illaa khayruka wa laa tayra illaa tayruka wa laa
>   ilaaha ghayruka (O Allaah, there is no good except Your good, no birds
>   (omens) except from You, and there is no god beside You).” [Classed as
>   hasan by al-Arna’oot and as saheeh by al-Albaani in Saheeh al-Jaami’,
>   no. 6264]